# With RSpec, is there a way to define a before(:each) for a describe block?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rspec2

Right now my rpsec goes like this:

```
describe Ability do

  before(:each) do
  end

  describe 'xxx' do
    it "should xxx" do
    end
    it "should xxx" do
    end
  end

  describe 'xxx' do
    it "should xxx" do
    end
    it "should xxx" do
    end
  end

  describe 'xxx' do
    it "should xxx" do
    end
    it "should xxx" do
    end
  end

  describe 'xxx' do
    it "should xxx" do
    end
    it "should xxx" do
    end
  end

end
```

Is there a way I can define a before each for just one of the describe blocks? Something like this:

```
describe Ability do

  before(:each) do
  end

  describe 'xxx' do
    it "should xxx" do
    end
    it "should xxx" do
    end
  end

  describe 'xxx' do
    it "should xxx" do
    end
    it "should xxx" do
    end
  end

  describe 'xxx' do
    it "should xxx" do
    end
    it "should xxx" do
    end
  end

  describe 'xxx' do

    before(:each) do
      XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
    end

    it "should xxx" do
    end
    it "should xxx" do
    end
  end

end
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution you gave should work. Have you tried it ?